# Is it possible to implement `Functor<T>` in Java?

Tags: java, haskell, functor

I stumbled upon a little problem today. Consider a little wrapper class:

```
class Event<T> {
   T value;
   Class<T> type;
   // other fields, getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Now I was in a situation where I wanted to convert a `Event<Long>` into a `Event<String>` while preserving the other fields and updating the `type` member.

Eventually I ended up with the most simple "solution":

```
Event<String> new = new Event(old.getValue().toString(), String.class, other, fields);
```

Having worked with Haskell on my pet projects however, I naturally longed for a function like `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` (read: given a function from a to b and a functor containing something of type a give me a result containing the b) and after finding no standard implementation I set out to write one myself:

```
interface Functor<T> {
  Functor<S> fmap( Func1<T,S> f );
}

// ... in Event<T>:

Functor<S> fmap( Func1<T,S> f ) { 
  S newValue = f.call(this.value);
  return new Event( newValue, newValue.getClass(), other, fields);
}
```

Now there is a problem with this solution: after the call to fmap in Java I am left with an instance of type `Functor<String>` while the same function in Haskell would return a `Event<String>`.

Is there a way to get my `Event` back (without unsafely casting it)?

Comment: You'll need higher kinded polymorphism here. You need to abstract over both the S and T variables but also the part called Functor.

Comment: Java's type system can't really represent higher-kinded type constructors.

Comment: Change the return type of `fmap` in the `Event` class to `Event<S>`. Since `Event` is a subclass of `Functor` this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works reasonably well for me, but it's not quite `Functor<T>`.  It requires that you also specify `F`, the type for which your functor is an instance:

```
interface Fn1<A, B> {
  B apply(A a);
}

interface Functor<A, F extends Functor<?, ?>> {
  <B> F map(Fn1<A, B> f);
}
```

Your `Event<A>` class would implement `Functor` like this:

```
public class Event<A> implements Functor<A, Event<?>> {

  public final A value;

  public Event(A _value) {
    value = _value;
  }

  public <B> Event<B> map(Fn1<A, B> f) {
    return new Event<B>(f.apply(value));
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "Event<" + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + ">(" + value.toString() + ")";
  }
}
```

If you need a functor for a closed-to-extension class (e.g. `Observable` from rxjava), you can write one that looks a little more like a type class, however it won't be able to conform to any functor-like interface since Java lacks higher-kinded types:

```
public class ObservableFunctor {
  public static <A,B> Observable<B> map(Observable<A> fa, Fn1<A, B> f) {
    return new Observable<B>(f.apply(fa.value));
  }
}
```

Here's a runnable example that uses both `Event` and `Observable` from above:

```
public class FunctorDemo {

  interface Fn1<A, B> {
    B apply(A a);
  }

  interface Functor<A, F extends Functor<?, ?>> {
    <B> F map(Fn1<A, B> f);
  }

  static class ObservableFunctor {
    public static <A,B> Observable<B> map(Observable<A> fa, Fn1<A, B> f) {
      return new Observable<B>(f.apply(fa.value));
    }
  }

  static class Observable<A>  {

    public final A value;

    public Observable(A _value) {
      value = _value;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "Observable<" + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + ">(" + value.toString() + ")";
    }
  }

  static class Event<A> implements Functor<A, Event<?>> {

    public final A value;

    public Event(A _value) {
      value = _value;
    }

    public <B> Event<B> map(Fn1<A, B> f) {
      return new Event<B>(f.apply(value));
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "Event<" + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + ">(" + value.toString() + ")";
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Observable<Event<Long>> oe1 = new Observable(new Event(42L));
    System.out.println("oe1: " + oe1.toString()); // oe1: Observable<Event>(Event<Long>(42))

    Observable<Event<String>> oe2 = ObservableFunctor.map(oe1,
      new Fn1<Event<Long>, Event<String>>() {
        public Event<String> apply(Event<Long> e) {
          return e.map(
            new Fn1<Long, String>() {
              public String apply(Long l) {
                return l.toString();
              }
            }
          );
        }
      }
    );
    System.out.println("oe2: " + oe2.toString()); // oe2: Observable<Event>(Event<String>(42))

  }
}
```

Comment: But sadly doesn't work for me ... don't know why. Have some nested generics (`Observable<Event<Float[]>>>`) ... and it just doesn't want to play nice with this.

Comment: Do you also need `Observable` to be/have a functor?

Comment: I updated the above example to make a nested `Observable<Event<Long>>` type.  Does this get closer to what you need?

Comment: Naa ... the problem is that `Observable` is from rxjava and closed to me, so I can't extend it in any way.

Comment: Ah, that makes it tricky.  I updated the above so that `Observable` is not a functor, and a functor-like `ObservableFunctor` is used instead.

Answer (score 8):

No, it isn't possible. For this to happen we would need to abstract over the `Functor` in your interface, something like

```
interface Functor<T> as F<T> {
    F<S> map(f : Function<T, S>);
}
```

But Java doesn't allow you to abstract over *type constructors*, just *types*. This is called Higher Kinded Types (HKT). Only a few (non-dependent) languages have HKTs, Scala and Haskell are the only two I can think of.

In fact HKTs are necessary to express a lot of abstractions,

1. Control.Monad
2. Control.Applicative
3. Data.Traversable
4. Data.Foldable
5. Control.Monad.Trans
6. Any monad transformers, full stop
7. Free monads
8. Lenses/Prisms
9. Streaming libraries (they're monad transformers)
10. Almost everything that was in `category-extras`

All of these involve abstracting over type constructors, not just concrete types.

Comment: This is possible in c#, see the second half of the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21366216/414413. I'm not familiar enough with Java generics to say if the same trick is possible in Java.

Comment: Java lets an implementing / extending class to change the return type of a method to a subclass of the return type of the parent's method (http://pastebin.com/4vzAVVTN) so that should help with OP's problem.