# C# Continuation Monad Implementation

Tags: c#, haskell, functional-programming, monads

I have been working on allowing function chaining. I have created a class called continuationmonad which takes a value, and a function from a => b. This allows me to use fmap and bind to chain these together. I have also used lazy to allowed calls to be defered where possible.

Is this class really the continuation monad or is it something else. I am finding it hard to find good literature which is not is Haskell.

Also any comments on how to improve / correct this.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace Monads
{

    public class Continuation<Input, Output>{
        public Continuation(Input value, Func<Input,Output> function){
            this.value = new Lazy<Input>( () => value);
            this.function = function;
        }

        public Continuation(Lazy<Input> value, Func<Input,Output> function){
            this.value = value;
            this.function = function;
        }

        public Continuation<Output, Result> FMap<Result>(Func<Output, Result> map){
            return new Continuation<Output, Result>(new Lazy<Output>( () => Run() ), x => map(x));
        }

        public Continuation<Output,Result> Bind<Result>(Func<Output, Continuation<Output, Result>> f){
            return f(Run());
        }

        public Output Run(){
            return function(value.Value);
        }

        private Func<Input, Output> function;
        private Lazy<Input> value;
    }

    public static class ContinuationExtension{
        public static Continuation<A,B> Unit<A,B>(this Func<A,B> f, A value){
            return new Continuation<A, B>(value,f);
        }

        public static Continuation<A,B> Unit<A,B>(this A value,Func<A,B> f){
            return new Continuation<A, B>(value,f);
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class MonadTests
    {

        public Continuation<int,int> Wrapped(int value){
            return new Continuation<int,int>(value, x => x * 10);
        }

        [Test]
        public void ContinuationMonadTests()
        {

            var number = 42;
            var result = number.Unit(x => x + 8).FMap(x => x * 2).Bind(Wrapped).Run();

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the [continuation monad](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/12/the-continuation-monad.html). You are much closer to the Haskell `Monad` instance for functions.

You aren't getting anything that you couldn't get just from using `Lazy<>`. Since you have provided the input when you build an instance of your class, you aren't building functions, you are building values that are determined by a computation that hasn't been evaluated yet. `Lazy<>` delays the evaluation of computation until the value is needed.

Let's put together something like the Haskell `Monad` instance for functions in c#. LINQ syntax has established the convention for  `Monad`s in c#. They should have:

- a `Select` extension method analogous to a Haskell `Functor`'s `fmap`
- a `SelectMany` extension method analogous to Haskell's `Monad`'s `>>=`
- an additional `SelectMany` that LINQ syntax uses. This takes an additional function that combines the value from two steps together.

Unfortunately, there's no convention for what the analog of a `Monad`'s `return` should be called; we'll call ours `Constant`. Unfortunately, `Constant` won't be very convenient because c#'s type inference won't be able to figure out the types.

```
public static class Function
{
    public static Func<TIn, TOut> Constant<TIn, TOut>(TOut result)
    {
        return x => result;
    }

    public static Func<TIn, TOut> Select<TIn, TMid, TOut>(
        this Func<TIn, TMid> func,
        Func<TMid, TOut> proj)
    {
        return x => proj(func(x));
    }

    public static Func<TIn, TOut> SelectMany<TIn, TMid, TOut>(
        this Func<TIn, TMid> func,
        Func<TMid, Func<TIn, TOut>> proj)
    {
        return x => proj(func(x))(x);
    }

    public static Func<TIn, TOut> SelectMany<TIn, TMid1, TMid2, TOut>(
        this Func<TIn, TMid1> func,
        Func<TMid1, Func<TIn, TMid2>> proj1,
        Func<TMid1, TMid2, TOut> proj2)
    {
        return x => {
            var mid1 = func(x);
            var mid2 = proj1(mid1)(x);
            return proj2(mid1, mid2);
        };
    }
}
```

Note that defining these extension methods only lets you interact with something like it's a `Monad`, it doesn't let you write code that's generic over the specific `Monad` being used. There's a sketch of how to do that in the [second half of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21366216/414413).

Comment: Your answer did pop up in the same instant I just hit the button :D - +1 for the surely better answer

Comment: why can't `Func<,>` be the first value of an extension method? Seems to work fine on first glance: https://gist.github.com/CarstenKoenig/26e46150c6458609d756

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit opinion based but I'll try to give you my 5ct anyway.

Let's have a look at your class and their instances:

It includes a value and a function where you (tried) to make it all a lazy.
From a theoretical view I can see no difference to `Lazy<T>` on first glance:

You can surely convert one of your `Continuation<Input,Output>` to just a `Lazy<Output>`.

The same is true for the reverse: given some lazy value `a` you can make a instance with just

```
new Continuation(a, x => x)
```

So to me it seems that you just reinvented `Lazy` (which is an monad, in Haskell you would call it [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Identity.html).

The `Cont` monad is not really easy to crasp but it's really more related to .net-Events or .net-Observables. The datastructure itself would be like

```
Func<Func<Input,Output>, Output>
```

Where you pass in a continuation `Func<Input,Output>` to some *internal* calculation and then the struture than will call it when it *has calculated an input* `Input` to get the final result.

This might be a bit cryptic but one .net application are the `Async` workflows F# uses and which stood model for C#s async/await behaviour in some sense.

I have some material I used for a talk on a simpified version of this monad in C# [on github](https://github.com/CarstenKoenig/DWX2014/tree/master/Monads/Monaden%20Solution/Monaden.CSharp/Continuation) maybe you'll find it interesting.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that `Lazy<>` is Haskell's `Identity`. In c# an idiomatic `Identity` would probably be strict.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a very comprehensive introduction to the Continuation monad that you can Find Here  [Discovering the Continuation Monad in C#](https://medium.com/@dimpapadim3/deriving-continuation-monad-from-callbacks-23d74e8331d0)

Also you can find a.Net Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yP02m0)

I Repeat it in summary here 
Starting from an initial Function

```
int Square(int x ){return (x * x);}
```

2. Use Callback and remove return type

```
    public static void Square(int x, Action<int> callback)
    {
    callback(x * x);
    }
```

3. Curry the Callback

```
    public static Action<Action<int>> Square(int x)
    {
     return (callback) => { callback(x * x); };
    }
```

4. Generalize the returned Continuation

```
    public static Func<Func<int,T>,T> Square<T>(int x)
    {
         return (callback) => { callback(x * x); };
    }
```

5. Extract the Continuation Structure Also Known As the Return Method of the monad. That is Give me a value and i will give you a Monad for this value

```
    //((U→ T) → T)

       delegate T Cont<U, T>(Func<U, T> f);

    public static Cont<U, T> ToContinuation<U, T>(this U x)
    {
       return (callback) => callback(x);
    }

    square.ToContinuation<Func<int, int>, int>()
```

6. Add The bind Monadic method and thus Complete the Monad.That is Give me a Two Monads and i will combine them to a new monad

((A→ T) → T)→( A→((B→ T) → T))→ ((B→ T) → T)

```
    public static Cont<V, Answer> Bind<T, U, V, Answer>(
    this Cont<T, Answer> m,
    Func<T, Cont<U, Answer>> k, 
    Func<T, U, V> selector)
    {
     return (Func<V, Answer> c) => 
    m(t => k(t)(y => c(selector(t, y))));
    }
```